# Why is there a difference in angles of deflection in Rutherford model?

Tags: scattering, atoms, coulombs-law

In Rutherford's model why were the angles of deflection different from each other?why were the deflections of large angles so less in number and was there a difference in deflections from protons and neutrons?

Answer (score 1):

Summarized from a comment-as-answer discussion:

The alpha particles "bounce" off of the positively charged nucleus.  The distances between the incoming alpha particle and the heavy nuclei are randomly distributed. A direct hit would bounce straight back, while a more distant pass would barely be displaced.